# Send code to kernel via a HTTP handler in a jupyter kernelgateway custom personality

Tags: websocket, tornado, jupyter

I am able to connect to the jupyter kernel gateway websocket personality, access the http endpoints and send messages to the kernel via the websocket.

How can I add an http handler that sends a predefined message through the websocket to the kernel?

For example, I want to add a `localhost:8888/load_data` handler that sends a message to the jupyter kernel to open a specific file.

[I know how to add a handler through a custom personality. I just wonder how to send a message from an http handler to the kernel (e.g. via the websocket or ZMQ) from a custom personality.]

Comment: There is [Python Client Example in Jupyter official documentation](https://github.com/jupyter/kernel_gateway_demos/tree/master/python_client_example) based on Tornado which shows how to connect Jupyter Kernel gateway. Just wrap Tornado's handler around it.